# HBase: PriviledgedActionException when run PerformanceEvaluation

Tags: hadoop, hbase, cloudera

I installed HBase (Version 0.90.6-cdh3u4) in a Hadoop cluster. I want to test the performance. However I ran

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.PerformanceEvaluation sequenalWrite 2
```

from the machine on which the HMaster run, the performance evaluation submit a map-reduce job to Hadoop. But the job failed with these messages:

> 2012-07-26 12:45:17,733 ERROR
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation:
>   PriviledgedActionException as:root (auth:SIMPLE)
>   cause:org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedWithDetailsException:
>   Failed 22193 actions: servers with issues: test-8:60020,  2012-07-26
>   12:45:17,734 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child: Error running child
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedWithDetailsException:
>   Failed 22193 actions: servers with issues: test-8:60020,      at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.processBatch(HConnectionManager.java:1485)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.processBatchOfPuts(HConnectionManager.java:1499)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.flushCommits(HTable.java:859)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.PerformanceEvaluation$Test.testTakedown(PerformanceEvaluation.java:754)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.PerformanceEvaluation$Test.test(PerformanceEvaluation.java:771)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.PerformanceEvaluation.runOneClient(PerformanceEvaluation.java:1098)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.PerformanceEvaluation$EvaluationMapTask.map(PerformanceEvaluation.java:447)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.PerformanceEvaluation$EvaluationMapTask.map(PerformanceEvaluation.java:400)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:647)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:323)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:270)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1177)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:264) 2012-07-26
>   12:45:17,740 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task: Runnning cleanup for
>   the task

Then I tried some other map-reduce jobs, all of them could finish successfully. So I think the Hadoop itself works well.

Also, operations in Hbase Shell are OK. I can create tables, put some data... This exception only occurs when running PerformanceEvaluation.

Could anyone know how to fix it?